Is the Microsoft "Deploy to Azure" button ever localized?
Microsoft provides developers with an embeddable button that allows them to deploy remote templates. Azure Resource Manager templates.
From the docs "This article describes how to use the Deploy to Azure button to deploy remote ARM JSON templates from a GitHub repository or an Azure storage account. You can add the button directly to the README.md file in your GitHub repository. Or, you can add the button to a web page that references the repository." it seems this button is suggested to be used in READMEs or web pages only.
For example when I view this button in a translated page in GitHub, the button continues to stay in English, so it seems it like it is not being localized regardless of where it is being embedded. This must be the expected behavior?
Is anyone aware if my assumption of the expected behavior is correct or know of anyway to localize this button? Since it is just an SVG (source: https://aka.ms/deploytoazurebutton), I think it is safe to assume the expectation from Microsoft is that this button is never to be localized.

Screenshot taken from here.
